# Reading from text files until String max length

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to coding in Dart so please bear with me. I searched up how to read files with the readAsString() function from the flutter API. It says that it will read the entire content of the file and return it as a String. However, is there some sort of String max size that it can only read? I could not find the max size of a String in Dart online. Thanks.

Here's the code in case you want a look:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class Storage {
  Future<String> get localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get localFile async {
    final path = await localPath;
    return File('$path/data.txt');
  }

  Future<List<String>> read() async {
    try {
      final file = await localFile;
      String contents = await file.readAsString(); //the important part
      return contents.split(";");
    } catch (exception) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  void write(List data) async {
    final file = await localFile;
    String toWrite = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      toWrite += data.elementAt(i) + ";";
    }
    file.writeAsString(toWrite);
  }
}
```

Comment: With `String contents = await file.readAsString();`, you want to limit the length of `contents `? If yes, you want to split for the start ?

Comment: Like the comment below, I want to know if it is able to read an indefinitely large String using readAsString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
var myFileStream = File('path/to/file').openRead();
var firstChars = myFileStream.take(1024);
```

This will limit the memory part of the file to the first 1024 characters.

(I think. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I meant is there a max file size that it will read. Ex. The  readAsString() function returns only the first x number of characters before it exceeds the size of a String.

Comment: No, Strings are "until you run out of memory".